# Creating an Image from a Textfile Data using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

With the below lines of code, I am breaking the 64x64 size colored image and storing it in a text file after normalization.

```
input_image_filename = './Images/Image_64x64.jpg'; % A 64x64 size colored image
input_image_3D = imread(input_image_filename);      % Breaking image into pixel
value_data=  double(reshape(input_image_3D,[],1));
%norm_image_3D= value_data/norm(value_data);

fid= fopen('filename_test1.txt','wt');             
fprintf(fid,'%0.16f\n',value_data); % Written the image to file
fclose(fid);


filename = 'filename_test1.txt';
testing_image_filename= './Testing_64x64_output.jpg';
testingReadFile= importdata(filename);
data_in_matrix_form= double(reshape(testingReadFile,[64 64 3]));


imwrite(data_in_matrix_form,testing_image_filename);
imshow(data_in_matrix_form);
```

After this, suppose I want to generate the image back from the textfile data, how should I do that?
The output image looks different from the input image.

The Input image is
[image]

The output image I am getting is [image].

Comment: "does not work" is not a very helpful problem description, particularly when we don't have your image to try your code on.

Comment: Thank you @beaker for the response. I have modified the code and added the image and result. Please help me correcting the code.

Comment: You're trying to display uint8 data that you've cast to double. Use `data_in_matrix_form= uint8(reshape(testingReadFile,[64 64 3]));`

Comment: @beaker   This gave  completely black image

Comment: You put the `norm` back in, didn't you...

Comment: Thank you @beaker for great help. Without putting the  norm  is works correctly.